# WSDL with multi port in same service

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, wsdl

I want use a WSDL file who wrote.

With two porttypes

```
    <wsdl:portType name="ContentDirectory">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSortCapabilities">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetSortCapabilitiesRequest" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetSortCapabilitiesResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSystemUpdateID">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:NOTHING_INPUT" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetSystemUpdateIDResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:portType name="ConnectionManager">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCurrentConnectionIDs">
      <wsdl:input message= "tns:NOTHING_INPUT" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCurrentConnectionIDsResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation> 
    <wsdl:operation name="GetProtocolInfo">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:NOTHING_INPUT" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetProtocolInfoResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation> 
  </wsdl:portType>
```

And two binding

```
 <wsdl:binding name="ContentDirectory" type="tns:ContentDirectory">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Browse">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.forge.soa4d.org/DPWS/Samples/MediaRenderer/Browse/" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSystemUpdateID">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.forge.soa4d.org/DPWS/Samples/MediaRenderer/GetSystemUpdateID/" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="ConnectionManager" type="tns:ConnectionManager">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCurrentConnectionIDs">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.forge.soa4d.org/DPWS/Samples/MediaRenderer/GetCurrentConnectionIDs/" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetProtocolInfo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.forge.soa4d.org/DPWS/Samples/MediaRenderer/GetProtocolInfo/" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
```

And service with two ports

```
  <wsdl:service name="Media">
    <wsdl:port name="ContentDirectory" binding="tns:ContentDirectory">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/MediaServer/TESTWSDL" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="ConnectionManager" binding="tns:ConnectionManager">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/MediaServer/TESTWSDL" />
    </wsdl:port> 
  </wsdl:service>
```

When I use this service with only one port my client able read my WSDL.
When I use this service  with two ports getting an error. (same with a different location)

I didn't find in W3 WSDL spec a problem with that.

What is the solution?

Comment: No idea for this WSDL file ?

Comment: Was this WSDL built manually, or auto-generated from a service?